# VisualStudioCode error 405 in post method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Goodmorning, I'm creating a Website with VisualStudioCode and I have a javascript with which I would like to run a php code in server side. I call it with ajax but always appears the error "405 (method not allowed)". Can someone help me to solve this problem? thank you very much

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: thank you for your reply...I solved with Apache. Thank you very much. Best Regards